# popup.html file not included inside chrome extension build using vite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm using [this github cli plugin](https://github.com/guocaoyi/create-chrome-ext) to scaffold mv3 chrome extensions using vue and vite.

The template is created correctly and I'm able to work on it, but I have a problem when I want to use the `chrome.window.create` or `chrome.tabs.create`, when I run the build command the final folder will not contain the `popup.html` file, it will be bundled only if is used inside the `manifest.js` file that is used to generate the build

This is the manifest configuration

```js
import { defineManifest } from '@crxjs/vite-plugin'

export default defineManifest({
  name: '',
  description: '',
  version: '1.0.0',
  manifest_version: 3,
  icons: {
    16: 'img/logo-16.png',
    32: 'img/logo-34.png',
    48: 'img/logo-48.png',
    128: 'img/logo-128.png',
  },
//If I uncomment popup will be included but tabs and popup windows will not work
  action: {
    // default_popup: 'popup.html',
    // default_icon: 'img/logo-48.png',
  },
  //options_page: 'options.html',
  background: {
    service_worker: 'src/background/index.js',
    type: 'module',
  },
  content_scripts: [
    {
      matches: ['http://*/*', 'https://*/*'],
      js: ['src/content/index.js'],
    },
  ],
  host_permissions: [
    'https://*.herokuapp.com/*'
  ],
  web_accessible_resources: [
    {
      resources: ['img/logo-16.png', 'img/logo-34.png', 'img/logo-48.png', 'img/logo-128.png'],
      matches: [],
    },
  ],
  permissions: [
    'tabs',
    'gcm',
    'identity',
  ],
  oauth2: {
    "client_id": "...cd.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
    ]
  }
})
```

And this is the vite code I have

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { crx } from '@crxjs/vite-plugin'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

import manifest from './src/manifest.js'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const production = mode === 'production'

  return {
    build: {
      emptyOutDir: true,
      outDir: 'build',
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
          chunkFileNames: 'assets/chunk-[hash].js',
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: [crx({ manifest }), vue()],
  }
})
```

How I can fix the build to include the popup.html page or any custom html page I can need?

Comment: This is more of a question for the plugin you're attempting to use. Looks like they're doing some special abstraction. I've been wrestling with a Vue-based Chrome Extension too, mainly trying to implement Vue via content scripts. I've had success using another plugin (Vue3, with imports, working in both content script and popup): https://github.com/StarkShang/vite-plugin-chrome-extension